# Wanted to send 1 element at a time of an arraylist into sendkeys method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have created an `arraylist` of a valid/invalid email id(s), and wanted to send 1 element at a time into sendkeys method, like `index 0 = 'abc@gmail.com'` this should be tested on 1st iteration and then so on. but i'm unable to pause the loop in-between. The code below is sending both 2 items in `textfield` at once. Please help me.

```
    String array[] = {"abc@gmail.com","abc@gmail"};
    for(int i=0;i<=array.length;i++)
    {
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("exampleInputEmail"));
        email.sendKeys(array[i]);   
        
        Boolean a = EmailValidatior(email.getAttribute("value"));
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: it is not sending them at once, it is sending one after the other. Since you never clear the input field, they will just be "typed" after one another into the same input field. A pause is not fixing that, clear the field instead.

Comment: Thanks! it has solved my problem